# FormatType with respect to Cell's content

Tags: front-end, options, stylesheet, inheritance

#### Minimal example:

Let's establish a notebook's stylesheet with additional `TestStyle` which has a `FormatType->"CellExpression"`:

```
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[],
 StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData["Notebook"], Background -> LightBlue],
    Cell[StyleData["TestStyle"], FormatType -> "CellExpression"]
    }]
 ]
```

and let's create couple of examples:

```
CellPrint[Cell[BoxData["TestStyle"], "TestStyle"]]

CellPrint[Cell[TextData["TestStyle"], "TestStyle"]]

CellPrint[Cell["TestStyle", "TestStyle"]]
```

#### Problem:

The first one doesn't respect `FormatType` (`Background` should be `White`). I can imagine it is to be expected but I failed to explain it to myself.

[image]

#### Question:

What exactly do I have to keep in mind about interference between `Cell` contents and `FormatType` or other options. `Background` inherited from `CellExpression` shouldn't care about the content so there is probably something more general to remember.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Cell[TextData["string"]]` is completely equivalent to `Cell["string"]`.  There's no reason to expect the two to behave differently.  `TextData` is a required wrapper when the contents are more complex than a string, but when it's a string, it changes nothing.  And TextData cells have only a single way of determining the format type...from the `FormatType` option.

While TextData must rely on the `FormatType` option for its notion of format type, BoxData relies instead on the `FormBox` wrapper.  You can see evidence of this by evaluating...

```
Dynamic[CurrentValue[FormatType]]
```

If you convert the output cell to TraditionalForm, you'll see the dynamic update.  But note that nowhere in the underlying cell expression is `FormatType->TraditionalForm` set.  Nor is it set in the `"TraditionalForm"` style in Core.nb.  This is the FE trying to keep the `FormBox` and option forms of `FormatType` in sync.

When a BoxData cell has no `FormBox`, then it's StandardForm.  Always.  This is hard-coded and cannot be overridden.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the answer. Could you also tell me what decides if TextData or BoxData appears when one starts typing in an empty cell?

Comment: @Kuba the `DefaultFormatType` option.

Comment: What determines if `TextData` or `BoxData` appears in an inline cell?  [I am trying to get inline cells to use `TextData`, but I am unable to convince it to do that by setting the `DefaultInlineFormatType` option.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156424/12)

Comment: If you're talking about creating inline cells using Ctrl+9, then it's always toggling.  If the cell you're in is `TextData`, then it will insert a `BoxData` cell and vice versa.  Because this is 99% of what people use inline cells for.  If you want something else, you have to programmatically create the cell, or insert it in Show Cell Expression mode, or a few other tech-y options.

Comment: @JohnFultz so there's no way to force an inline cell inside a block of text (e.g. when I want to have $ a_b $ in a `"Text"` cell) use `TextData` instead outside of some hideous hack...? That seems wrong.