# How to make tabs aligned in Print?

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, grid-layouts, alignment, named-characters

For example,

```
Print["1\t55
33\t44"]
```

outputs

> [image]

Why tab is not aligned? If tab is not aligned, why is it called tab? Is there a way to make tabs aligned?

Answer (score 9):

`Print` isn't really meant to do text-processor-like formatting. It most common use it to display intermediate results where people don't care much about pretty-printing. It produces an output cell where a tab character in a string is replaced with four spaces as is illustrated below.

```
 Print["12345678\n1\t55\n33\t44"]
```

[image: output]

There are lots of ways to get the kind of formatting you want. Here is one of them, which requires only a little modification of your code.

```
CellPrint[TextCell["1\t55\n33\t44", "Text"]]
```

[image: text]

Comment: (+1) Is it documented anywhere that in `Print` output "a tab character in a string is replaced with four spaces"?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov. Not that I know of. I just counted the spaces.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thank you so much! +1

Answer (score 3):

`StandardForm` does not support tabs or newlines like regular text editor. It doesn't make sense to do so considering variety of 2D typesetting available there.

One can't even type `\t` unless it is a beginning of the line.

[tutorial / NewlinesAndTabsInStrings](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NewlinesAndTabsInStrings.html):

> You should realize that even though it is possible to achieve some formatting of Wolfram Language output by creating strings which contain raw tabs and newlines, this is **rarely a good idea**. Typically a much better approach is to use the higher-level Wolfram Language formatting primitives [...`Column` etc]. These primitives will always yield consistent output, independent of such issues as the positions of tab settings on a particular device.

And `Print` output is sent via `$Output` which `FormatType` is set to `StandardForm`.

In practice this means that your input goes through `Cell @ BoxData @ ToBoxes @ input` (roughly).

From what I've tried only `TextForm` respects tabs. It is used in styles like `Code / Program / Text` etc. Those cells contain `TextData` or just plain string inside instead of `BoxData`.

So the quick fix is:

```
Print @ TextCell["1\t55\n33\t44"]
```

or

```
Print @ RawBoxes @ Cell["1\t55\n33\t44"]
```

By the way, what documentation meant by *"higher-level Wolfram Language formatting primitives"* is something like:

```
Print @ Grid[ImportString["a\t55\n33\t44", "Table"], Alignment -> Left]
```

Comment: [Citing](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Dec/msg00462.html) John Fultz, "`Cell[_String]` is equivalent to `Cell[TextData[{_String}]]`." Also [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124395/280).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov yep, also mentioned in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110018/5478