# Is there a function similar to Print which really respects tabs and newlines?

Tags: output-formatting, grid-layouts, printing, alignment

I am looking for something which acts like `Print`, preferably with the same syntax, which lets me arrange things in columns of proper width (i.e. if an item in a column is wider than the elements below it, the whole column is made as wide as necessary to represent it).

In order to assign something to the next column, I want to use `\t`. In order to assign the stuff following to a new row, I want to use `\n`. I want an option `WordWrap` to let it word wrap things in a column if the column would become too wide to let the whole output be represented. Another useful option would be `Hyphenate`. One also needs some options to define the minimum/maximum column width for the particular columns and the maximum width of the whole output.

Since there are already so many practical things im Mma, most probably something of what I have outlined is already present. On the other hand, in  [there was a similar but less general question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144067/how-to-make-tabs-aligned-in-print), suggesting to use

```
Print @ Grid[ImportString["a\t55\n33\t44", "Table"], Alignment -> Left]
```

`ImportString` however separates columns not only at `\t`, but also at a space.

```
Print @ Grid[ImportString["a 55\n33 44", "Table"], Alignment -> Left]
```

yields the same results as the example above.

```
Print @ Grid[ImportString["a lengthy string with spaces 55\n33 44", "Table"], Alignment -> Left]
```

therefore arranges the word `lengthy` into the same column as `44`. Further `ImportString` strictly requires a string as its first parameter. I would like to use what `Print` offers.

If there would be some function called `PrettyPrint`, I would like it to invoke it like `Print`, e.g.

```
PrettyPrint["This goes to the first column\tand this to the second one\n"
, "x=", x, "\tx^2=\t", x^2, "\tSquares are easyly computed by hand.\n"
, "x=", x, "\tSqrt[x]=\t",Sqrt[x], "\tSquare roots are more difficult.\n"
, "x=", 2, "\tSqrt[x]=\t",Sqrt[2], "\teasy as a symbol\n"
, "x=", 2., "\tSqrt[x]=\t",Sqrt[2.], "\tendless numerical work."
, WordWrap->True
, Hyphenate->English
, MinColumnWidth->{"1 cm","1 cm","3 cm",Automatic}
, MaxColumnWidth->{"3 cm","3 cm","5 cm",Automatic}
, MaxWidth->"17 cm"
];
```

Answer (score 6):

> I am looking for something which acts like `Print`, preferably with the same syntax...

> ... `ImportString` strictly requires a string as its first parameter. I would like to use what `Print` offers.

You know that `Print` doesn't have options, because it must print arguments of any type, including options. Hence if you want to handle options, you need either other syntax, or specify options separately.

---

Here is a quick try on what you seemingly wish to achieve (without options handling):

```
PrettyPrint[args__] := 
 Print@Module[{tab, newline}, 
   Grid[Map[TextCell[Row[#]] &, 
      Split[#, # =!= tab &] & /@ 
       Split[Flatten[
         Replace[{args}, {s_String :> StringSplit[s, {"\t" -> tab, "\n" -> newline}]}, 1],
          1], # =!= newline &], {2}] /. {tab | newline -> Nothing}, Alignment -> Left]]
```

With your example:

```
PrettyPrint["This goes to the first column\tand this to the second one\n", "x=", x, "\t\
x^2=\t", x^2, "\tSquares are easyly computed by hand.\n", "x=", x, "\tSqrt[x]=\t", 
 Sqrt[x], "\tSquare roots are more difficult.\n", "x=", 2, "\tSqrt[x]=\t", 
 Sqrt[2], "\teasy as a symbol\n", "x=", 2., "\tSqrt[x]=\t", 
 Sqrt[2.], "\tendless numerical work."]
```

> [image: output]

If you reduce the width of the Notebook window, columns widths are automatically adapted and proper word-wrapping is applied to long rows of text:

> [image: output]

With an example TSV file imported as `"Text"`:

```
tsv = Import["ExampleData/classification.tsv", "Text"];
PrettyPrint[tsv]
```

> [image: output]

---

One possible approach to handle options is to specify them separately via `Options[PrettyPrint]`:

```
Options[PrettyPrint] = {ColumnWidths -> Automatic};
PrettyPrint[args__] := 
 Print@Module[{tab, newline}, 
   Grid[Map[TextCell[Row[#], 
        PageWidth -> OptionValue[Options[PrettyPrint], ColumnWidths]] &, 
      Split[#, # =!= tab &] & /@ 
       Split[Flatten[
         Replace[{args}, {s_String :> StringSplit[s, {"\t" -> tab, "\n" -> newline}]}, 1],
          1], # =!= newline &], {2}] /. {tab | newline -> Nothing}, Alignment -> Left]]
```

Now with your example:

```
Options[PrettyPrint] = {ColumnWidths -> 150};
PrettyPrint["This goes to the first column\tand this to the second one\n", "x=", x, "\t\
x^2=\t", x^2, "\tSquares are easyly computed by hand.\n", "x=", x, "\tSqrt[x]=\t", 
 Sqrt[x], "\tSquare roots are more difficult.\n", "x=", 2, "\tSqrt[x]=\t", 
 Sqrt[2], "\teasy as a symbol\n", "x=", 2., "\tSqrt[x]=\t", 
 Sqrt[2.], "\tendless numerical work."]
```

> [image: output]

With this implementation the option `ColumnWidths` in fact determines the *maximum* column width, because when we reduce the window width, columns will become even narrower. Hence the *minimal* column width is actually determined by the minimal width of the whole `Grid`.

Comment: Alexey, thank you very much for your beautiful and extensive Answer. You transplant the rhs of option `ColumnsWidth` to the rhs of option `PageWidth` to `TextCell`. How would one apply the first of such widths to the first `TextCell` in a row, the second one to the second and so on if several column widths are given? (possibly repeating the last one if an insufficient number of them is given)

Comment: Alexey, `PageWidth->something` determines the maximum width of a column. How can I define a minimum column width? Of course, the window would have to be wide enough to allow the sum of all minimum column widths.

Comment: I just have found undocumented syntax form of `ImageSize` for `Pane`, which can be useful for implementing the `MinColumnWidth` and `MaxColumnWidth` functionality. It is `ImageSize -> {{minWidth, maxWidth}, Automatic}`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the solution from Alexey Popkov I have seen that the `RawInputForm` (**Shift-Ctl-r**) of the generated output is

```
Grid[{{TextCell[Row[{"This goes to the first column"}], PageWidth -> 150], 
    TextCell[Row[{"and this to the second one"}], PageWidth -> 150], Null, 
    Null}, {TextCell[Row[{"x=", x}], PageWidth -> 150], 
    TextCell[Row[{"x^2="}], PageWidth -> 150], TextCell[Row[{x^2}], 
     PageWidth -> 150], TextCell[Row[{"Squares are easily computed by hand."}], PageWidth -> 150]}, 
   {TextCell[Row[{"x=", x}], PageWidth -> 150], TextCell[Row[{"Sqrt[x]="}], 
     PageWidth -> 150], TextCell[Row[{Sqrt[x]}], PageWidth -> 150], 
    TextCell[Row[{"Square roots are more difficult."}], PageWidth -> 150]}, 
   {TextCell[Row[{"x=", 2}], PageWidth -> 150], TextCell[Row[{"Sqrt[x]="}], 
     PageWidth -> 150], TextCell[Row[{Sqrt[2]}], PageWidth -> 150], 
    TextCell[Row[{"easy as a symbol"}], PageWidth -> 150]}, 
   {TextCell[Row[{"x=", 2.}], PageWidth -> 150], TextCell[Row[{"Sqrt[x]="}], 
     PageWidth -> 150], TextCell[Row[{1.4142135623730951}], 
     PageWidth -> 150], TextCell[Row[{"endless numerical work."}], 
     PageWidth -> 150]}}, Alignment -> Left, 
  ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]
```

Looking closer at it shows me that each `TextCell` is equipped with an option `PageWidth -> 150`. If I remove those options beginning at the second row, the appearance of the output remains looks as before after applying `TraditionalForm` to the cell (mark the cell bracket, then press **Shift-Ctl-t**).

Then I have modified the widths of the columns like this:

```
Grid[{{TextCell[Row[{"This goes to the first column"}], PageWidth -> 80], 
    TextCell[Row[{"and this to the second one"}], PageWidth -> 150], Null, 
    Null}, {TextCell[Row[{"x=", x}]], TextCell[Row[{"x^2="}]], 
    TextCell[Row[{x^2}]], TextCell[
     Row[{"Squares are easyly computed by hand."}]]}, 
   {TextCell[Row[{"x=", x}]], TextCell[Row[{"Sqrt[x]="}]], 
    TextCell[Row[{Sqrt[x]}]], TextCell[
     Row[{"Square roots are more difficult."}]]}, 
   {TextCell[Row[{"x=", 2}]], TextCell[Row[{"Sqrt[x]="}]], 
    TextCell[Row[{Sqrt[2]}]], TextCell[Row[{"easy as a symbol"}]]}, 
   {TextCell[Row[{"x=", 2.}]], TextCell[Row[{"Sqrt[x]="}]], 
    TextCell[Row[{1.4142135623730951}]], 
    TextCell[Row[{"endless numerical work."}]]}}, Alignment -> Left, 
  ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]
```

and after **Shift-Ctl-t** the column width of the first column becomes smaller (maintaining the nice property mentioned by Alexey when I reduce the window width).

This might give a hint how to prepare for different column widths. - My example was less than optimal since the first line has less columns than the following ones, resulting in the two entries `Null` in the first line of the two-dimensional list to be shown.

One might further vary Alexey's output prepending it with a row only defining the columns widths and no text like this:

```
Grid[{{TextCell[Row[{""}], PageWidth -> 80], TextCell[Row[{""}], 
     PageWidth -> 80], TextCell[Row[{""}], PageWidth -> 150], 
    TextCell[Row[{""}], PageWidth -> 150]}, 
   {TextCell[Row[{"This goes to the first column"}]], 
    TextCell[Row[{"and this to the second one"}]], Null, Null}, 
   {TextCell[Row[{"x=", x}]], TextCell[Row[{"x^2="}]], TextCell[Row[{x^2}]], 
    TextCell[Row[{"Squares are easily computed by hand."}]]}, 
   {TextCell[Row[{"x=", x}]], TextCell[Row[{"Sqrt[x]="}]], 
    TextCell[Row[{Sqrt[x]}]], TextCell[
     Row[{"Square roots are more difficult."}]]}, 
   {TextCell[Row[{"x=", 2}]], TextCell[Row[{"Sqrt[x]="}]], 
    TextCell[Row[{Sqrt[2]}]], TextCell[Row[{"easy as a symbol"}]]}, 
   {TextCell[Row[{"x=", 2.}]], TextCell[Row[{"Sqrt[x]="}]], 
    TextCell[Row[{1.4142135623730951}]], 
    TextCell[Row[{"endless numerical work."}]]}}, Alignment -> Left, 
  ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}]
```

This observation gives rise to a not yet solved idea to provide two functions:

`PrintTableHeadline[headline_String, MaximumColumnWidths->list]` where `headline` is a string consisting of the column headlines, separated by `\t` and `list` is a list of numbers representing the column widths (preferably in some practical unit like cm or mm).

Then `PrettyPrint` should adopt the column widths from the last call to `PrintTableHeadline`, accept all kinds of parameters like Print and separate the generated output to the columns like before.

It remains the problem to append subsequent output as a new row to an existing `Grid`.