# How to prevent formatting as Mathematica code in inline cells?

Tags: notebooks, formatting, style, boxes

We can start a new inline cell using Insert → Typesetting → Start Inline Cell. This is often used to insert mathematical formulae in text cells.

Instead, I want to use it to insert small bits of non-Mathematica code in text cells, e.g. `std::vector<int>`.  Correspondingly, I set [`DefaultNewInlineCellStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultNewInlineCellStyle.html) to an appropriate custom style* in the notebook. I also changed the default format type to TextForm using [`DefaultInlineFormatType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultInlineFormatType.html).

[image]

Even so, any text I enter into this inline cell is automatically formatted as if it were Mathematica code.

[image]

Notice that the `::` was formatted as if it were a message, with `vector` in grey, and that the spacing around `<` and `>` are increased as if they were relational operators.

This is the cell expression:

```
Cell[TextData[{
 "The type ",
 Cell[BoxData[
  FormBox[
   RowBox[{
    RowBox[{"std", "::", "vector"}], "<", "int", ">"}], TextForm]], "InlineCode",
  FormatType->"TextForm"],
 " ..."
}], "Text"
]
```

**Question:** What exactly is controlling this automatic formatting? How can I prevent it?  Is it related to the fact that the inline cell gets `BoxData` by default (while the surrounding text cell gets `TextData`)?

If I could get the following cell, that would be perfect:

```
Cell[TextData[{
 "The type ",
 Cell["std::vector<int>", "InlineCode"],
 " ..."
}], "Text"]
```

[image]

Perhaps the answer is that inline cells are not meant for this, and one should use a `StyleBox` instead of a `Cell`. [But that is no longer easy to enter in M11.2.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156423/12)

---

Related:

- [How to change the style of part of a cell in 11.2?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156423/12)
- [equivalent of stylable HTML elements?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156351/12)

---

<sup>* For simplicity, you may simply set it to "Text" style. It does not make a difference for this question.</sup>

Comment: It seems that `ShowAutoStyles` or `LanguageCategory` don't affect `a::b`, which is at least strange. Also when text form inline cell is created inside a standard form cell, not text form like here, then it does not get this `FormBox` wrapper and everything is correct because `FormBox` brings standard form styles and hardcoded whatever FE thinks it should do with BoxData. Not to mention that InlineCell style can interfere even if it is not explicitly used. #dailyFun, hope JF could clarify, maybe you could ping him somewhere.

Comment: related: [full topic + comment298436_110018](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108135/formattype-with-respect-to-cells-content#comment298436_110018) or [a/14835](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14835/5478)

Comment: p.s. code to play with: `NotebookDelete@NextCell[];
CellPrint[Cell["Test ", "Text"]]; SelectionMove[
 NextCell[], After, CellContents];
FrontEndTokenExecute["CreateInlineCell"];
NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], "var::vec<int>"];` try it with regular Text cell like above and `Cell[BoxData@"Test ", "Text"]` :)

Comment: @Kuba Re your last comment. I find that very confusing. I thought that `TextData` (or no wrapper) is what makes things act like plain text (what I want), and BoxData is what causes this special auto-formatting. Now it looks like if the parent is `TextData`, then the child (i.e. the inline cell) will be `BoxData`. If the parent is `BoxData` then the child will be `TextData`. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is what I wanted to demonstrate, but I do not know why this happens :/